# Node server still launching with React Native Offline Bundle

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

I'm preparing my React Native iOS app to launch and I seem to be missing something. I've commented out the localhost URL in the AppDelegate.m file as shown here:

`// jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];`

I then uncommented the code to use the local bundle a few lines down:
`jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`

However when I run the project the build still launches a local server in the terminal. This seems wrong to me since I'm using the offline build setup.

I also uploaded the archived build up to iTunes Connect and it's been processing for over an hour which may be related to this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run on your ios device you need to connect it and select it as the build target from xcode

Comment: Yeah my device is connected via USB and it's selected as the build target.